# Python. Поиск пустых ячеек в списке

Tags: python, list

К примеру, есть список:

```
someList = [("1","2","3","","5","","7","8","9")]
```

и мне нужно найти все пустые ячейки и вывести их на экран.

Пробовал так:

```
for i in range(len(someList)):
    if ( "" in someList[0][i] ):
        print(someList[0][i])
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде есть несколько проблем:

1. Массив `someList` содержит один единственный элемент (который, правда, является кортежем). Как следствие, `len(someList)` вернет `1`. Вряд ли вы именно такого поведения ожидаете.
2. Элемент `someList[0][i]` - это не массив, а строка, поэтому к ней не применима конструкция `"" in someList[0][i]` (поиск пустой строки в любой строке всегда возвращает `True`).
3. Если все остальное работало бы правильно, код `someList[0][i]` выводил бы пустую строку. Сомневаюсь, что вы именно этого ждете. Логичнее было бы выводит индекс пустого элемента.

Правильный, работоспособный код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
someList = [("1","2","3","","5","","7","8","9")]

for i in range(len(someList[0])):
    if ("" == someList[0][i]):
        print(i)
    else:
        pass
```